# Dynamic Web Service (SOAP) provider in Java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, apache-axis

we share a lot of CSV files in our organisation, containing all sorts of information. I wrote a small Java program to monitor a certain shared folder and read new csv files. My goal is to allow reading and updating information through SOAP Web Services. My issue is that the information structure is not static, so I cannot create a WSDL file from my Java structure (for example using spring...). I would need to create a dynamic WSDL file.

I was looking into Axis2 (http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/) but I still feel that I am missing something, since I would need to build the java class with the WS definitions on the fly, then compile, build the .aar package and then move the file to the axis2 folder. This seems a bit heavy.

Basically I only need two methods:

- find(id) -> returning the row with specified ID, if ID is NULL then return all
- update(id) -> updates the row and here I would need the dynamic content since I need to pass on the field and type which should be updated.

For example I have a user.csv:

```
ID;FirstName;Age;Mail   
01;Stephanie;27;sb@somemail.com
```

which should generate something like this:

[...]

```
<xsd:element name="delete">
            <xsd:complexType>
               <xsd:sequence>
                  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="id" type="xsd:string" />
               </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
         </xsd:element>


<xsd:element name="insert">
            <xsd:complexType>
               <xsd:sequence>
                  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="id" type="xsd:string" />
                  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="FirstName" type="xsd:string" />
                  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Age" type="xsd:integer" />
                  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Mail" type="xsd:string" />
               </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
         </xsd:element>
```

[...]

Does anyone have a better way of doing this?

Cheers,
Stephanie

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple WS just with 2 operation with a body raw in xml.

The xml must be compliant with an external XSD non in WSDL. In the server you have all XSD and you can validate input and create an object with Jaxb for example, that you can use for CRUD operation on CSV.

Comment: So you suggest that I write the SWDL-file myself (generate it my self)? But then the end-point would not know how to handle the "fields" or am I mistaken?

Comment: you can put in a byte[] field an xml file rapresenting the input, ad in another field a unique ID for the endpoint to update, so in the server you can implement a factory pattern that give you an endpoint implementation based on unique ID. Now for the endpoint you have a specific XSD to validate the input in the other filed (byte[]) you can validate and create the correct object e make CRUD operation wherever you want. The master ws is just a router that knows the implementation for a key. All other XSD are shared externally with client, not part of the  WSDL